# value of $(f\times g)'$ . where $f'\times g$ and $f\times g'$ are given.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces

> If $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are vector function and
>
> $f'\times g= \langle t^2,3t^3,1+t \rangle$ and $f\times g'=\langle-t^2,2t^3,2-t\rangle.$ Then $(f\times g)'=$

What I try:

$(f\times g)'=f\times g'+g\times f'$

$= \langle -t^2,2t^3,2-t\rangle + \langle t^2,3t^3,1+t\rangle=\langle 0,5t^3,3\rangle$

But answer given as $\langle 2t^2,t^3,2t-1\rangle$

Seems that answer is obtained when we subtract these two.

Please help me how do I solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Please typset with \langle and \rangle ($\langle x \rangle$ e.g.) instead of <>. It looks much better.

Comment: You have to be careful with the order. The cross product is *not* commutative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct product rule for cross products is $(f\times g)' = f\times g' + f' \times g$. Since $g \times f' = - f' \times g$, this deals with your problem.